# Jersey как вернуть список элементов

Tags: java, jersey

Необходимо вернуть лист объектов по запросу.

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserEndpoint extends ServletContainer {
    private UserService service;

@POST
@Path("/get")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<User> getUsers() {
    service = new UserService(UserFactory.getInstance().getUserDao());
    return service.getAllUsers();
}
```

Еще пробовал так:

```
GenericEntity<List<User>> list = new GenericEntity<List<User>>(service.getAllUsers()) {};
Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok().entity(service.getAllUsers());
return rb.build();
```

Отправляю @POST http://localhost:8765/rest/users/get. Получаю ошибку 500

Вот такое исключение ловлю на сервере:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.logException Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
 javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type java.util.List<models.User>, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

pom.xml

```
<jersey.version>1.19.4</jersey.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Может кто подскажем в чем может быть дело ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Хорошие туториалы](https://o7planning.org/en/11217/create-java-restful-client-with-jersey-client)
Вам нужен раздел Java Web Service, там все найдете